# Touchpad detected as ps2 mouse

Tags: touchpad

I am on HP Pavilion 15 EC...it has an Elantech touchpad and since I switched to Linux I have been having this problem.

I updated the kernel to 5.10 did no good...on Kubuntu it once worked perfectly on live usb but then it stopped working completely and wasn't working after complete installation either. I tweaked a bit here and there at last changing the the grub menu command lines to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

The xinput output:

```
raxz@Plasma:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Have you removed the unnecessary Synaptics touchpad driver? ⇢ `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: What kind of linux you are using? Is it Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Remove all kernel parameters and add output of `xinput` to your question. With `psmouse.proto=bare` it will always be as a mouse.

Comment: @Pilot6 hey i added the xinput output and sorry my exams are going on so i replied so late

Comment: @Matigo done that

Comment: it looks like `psmouse.proto=bare` is still there. Did you `update-grub`?